# arch ; can't update libblockdev

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

Running a global update

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
core is up to date
extra is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
:: Replace libblockdev-utils with extra/libblockdev? [Y/n] Y
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: unresolvable package conflicts detected
error: failed to prepare transaction (conflicting dependencies)
:: libblockdev and libblockdev-utils are in conflict
```

So I try to manually remove libblockdev-utils

```
sudo pacman -R libblockdev-utils
checking dependencies...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libblockdev-utils' required by libblockdev
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libbd_utils.so=3-64' required by libblockdev
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libblockdev-utils' required by libblockdev-crypto
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libbd_utils.so=3-64' required by libblockdev-crypto
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libblockdev-utils' required by libblockdev-fs
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libbd_utils.so=3-64' required by libblockdev-fs
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libblockdev-utils' required by libblockdev-loop
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libbd_utils.so=3-64' required by libblockdev-loop
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libblockdev-utils' required by libblockdev-mdraid
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libbd_utils.so=3-64' required by libblockdev-mdraid
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libblockdev-utils' required by libblockdev-nvme
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libbd_utils.so=3-64' required by libblockdev-nvme
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libblockdev-utils' required by libblockdev-part
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libbd_utils.so=3-64' required by libblockdev-part
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libblockdev-utils' required by libblockdev-swap
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libbd_utils.so=3-64' required by libblockdev-swap
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libblockdev-utils' required by udisks2
:: removing libblockdev-utils breaks dependency 'libbd_utils.so=3-64' required by udisks2
```

What to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was stuck with this today, but figured it out thanks to this: [How do I force remove a package in Arch with pacman?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10178/how-do-i-force-remove-a-package-in-arch-with-pacman)

```bash
sudo pacman -Rdd libblockdev-utils
sudo pacman -S libblockdev
```